# What is the crt0.o error when cross compiling and how do I fix it?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, crt

The project I am working on at the minute must be compiled using a cross compiler. My `binutils` and `gcc` have been installed into `~/opt/cross`, however when I try to compile, I am faced with this error:

```
/home/george/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/6.1.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find crt0.o: No such file or directory
/home/george/opt/cross/lib/gcc/i686-elf/6.1.0/../../../../i686-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code uses only GCC's freestanding headers (my full compile command: `~/opt/cross/bin/i686-elf-gcc kernel.c tty.c -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra`).

So what is `crt0.o` and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Try adding `-nostdlib -nostdinc`, assuming, of course, that you don't use the C standard library or its includes.

Comment: `crt0` is a part of runtime library, implementing (among the others) the standard startup code (entry point) for the application. If you want it to be freestanding without standard libraries, you will have to implement the startup code yourself. Are you doing so?